# class member functions with pointer parameters

Tags: class, pointers, parameters, reference, memory-address

I have this homework assignment that is giving me a lot of trouble right now. My teacher is very vague in class and hard to communicate with. I will try very hard to articulate my thoughts here.
Here is the assignment:

> (3pts) Given the following class header file, write the class’ source
>   code for each of the accessor and mutator functions listed. (Pay
>   attention to how the functions have listed their parameters, varying
>   between passing by reference and by value.) Don’t forget to comment
>   your code – it counts!
>
> ```
> class Album {
>   private:
>       char * artist;  // band or singer’s name
>       char * title;   // title of the album
>       int year_released;  // year the album is released
>       char * record_label;    // name of company produced album
>       int num_songs;  // number of songs on the album
>       int num_minutes_long;   // length (mins) of album
>       char * genre;   // genre of artist (eg, rock, pop, …)
>   public:
>       //constructors
>       Album();
>       Album(char *& a, char *& t);
>
>       //deconstructor
>       ~Album();
>
>       //accessors and mutators
>       bool set_artist(char * a);
>       bool set_title(char * t);
>       bool set_year_released(int value);
>       bool set_record_label(char *& label);
>       bool set_num_songs(int value);
>       bool set_num_minutes_long(int value);
>       bool set_genre(char * g);
>       bool get_artist(char *& a);
>       bool get_title(char *& t);
>       int get_year_released();
>       bool get_record_label(char *& label);
>       int get_num_songs();
>       int get_num_minutes_long();
>       bool get_genre(char *& g);
> };
> ```

Here is my work so far:

```
bool Album::set_artist(char * a)
{
 *artist = a;
}

bool Album::set_title(char * t)
{
*title =  t;
}

bool Album::set_year_released(int value)
{
year_released = value;
}   

bool Album::set_record_label (char *& label)
{
*record_label = label;
}

bool Album::set_num_songs(int value)
{
num_songs = value;
}
bool Album::set_number_minutes_long(int value)
{
num_minutes_long = value;
}
bool Album::set_genre(char * g)
{
*genre = g;
}
bool Album::get_artist(char *& a)
{
return artist;
}
bool Album::get_title(char *& t)
{
return title;
}
int Album::get_year_released()
{
return year_released;
}

bool Album::get_record_label(char *& label)
{
return *record_label;
}
```

The input will be an array.

My questions:

1. First, am I on the right track?
2. When using `(char * a)` for a function, for example, this is passing the address of `a`, correct? so then `*artist=a;` changes what the address of `a` points to?
3. Also, the functions are bool when I would expect void. Why?
4. For all of the `set_xxx` functions, the parameter is `*`... but for set_record_label it is `*&`. That appears to be a mistake to me. Is that right?
5. What is the difference between `*&` and `*` as parameters?

Thank you for your time. I know there is a lot here.

Comment: "First, am I on the right track?" -- I don't know; is it even the right album? (yuk yuk yuk)

Comment: haha that was pretty funny actually

Answer (score 0):

1. **First, am I on the right track?**

   A bit to general , let's go into details. But at least, you did not provide the required comments.
2. **When using (char * a) for a function, for example, this is passing the address of a, correct?**

   No. It passes an address called `a`.

   **so then *artist=a; changes what the address of a points to?**

   This produces a type mismatch. `artist` is a pointer to `char`. `*artist` is the `char` variable `artist` points to. `a`  is, agian,  a pointer to `char`. So, you assign a pointer to a `char` variable => type mismatch.
3. **Also, the functions are bool when I would expect void. Why?**

   I have no idea why do you expect `void`. However, `bool` makes sense: It allows the function to report, whether the operation (with side effect!) was successful or not.
4. **For all of the set_xxx functions, the parameter is `*` ... but for
   set_record_label it is *&. That appears to be a mistake to me. Is
   that right?**

   Since your instructor stresses the use of different parameters, it is probably no error. However, in real life it would be a bad style.
5. **What is the difference between *& and * as parameters?**

   `*` describes a pointer, `&` a reference. The referenced value can be a pointer again. I suggest that you reread the section on types in your textbook.